# What is the best resource to find, e.g. the plural form of nouns such as "der Automatismus"?

Tags: noun, resource

I use [LEO](http://dict.leo.org) for looking up German words, but it often does not have the plural form of nouns, so for that I use [Biolingus](http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?lang=en&service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=Automatismus&iservice=&comment=&email=), but in the case of the noun "Automatismus", even Biolingus doesn't inform me (as I eventually found out from a colleague) that the plural from of it, is "Automatismen".

**What is an online resource which has the correct plural form of all German nouns?**

Comment: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Automatismus)

Comment: We have bunch of questions about dictionaries and special kinds of information users need to find in them, I think you'll find a nice one by looking in tags like [tag:resources].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=Automatismus), if you don't need translations in the same resource.

Comment: I second canoo. Note that both LEO and dict.cc link to canoo.net - just click on the i symbol next to a German entry, canoo.net is in the menu.