# Reference for accusative and dative forms

Tags: noun, reference

What is a good reference to look at the accusative and dative forms of nouns? I was looking at the word `Wille` in the [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/wille), and while in this case I can deduce from the examples that the accusative and dative forms are `Willen`, it would be nice to have a reference that includes this for every word.

One possible source is [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wille), but how reliable is that?

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/what-is-the-best-resource-to-find-e-g-the-plural-form-of-nouns-such-as-der-au - Canoo.net are quite an exhaustive ressource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good source is [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/), the online version of *the* German Wörterbuch (similar to Oxford Dictionary).

Enter the word you are looking for (in your example: "Wille") and press enter or click "Los" (german for "go").

You get a list of words that contain your search-string. In our example the first entry is "Wille" which is what you was looking for. Click at "Zum vollständigen Artikel klicken Sie hier." ("Click here for the complete article")

Now scroll down to "Grammatik". Here you find what you are looking for:

[image]